# Correct grammatical errors after getting PhD

Tags: phd, thesis, errors-erratum

I have a question I cannot find the answer in any place. After receiving my PhD degree I found in my thesis some stupid grammatical errors which dont change anything in my work but still embarrassing. Can I correct these errors? Is anybody has the same experience. Sometimes I found mistakes in books which are 5th edition so it can happen.. but still..

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Please [edit] your question to clarify: How is your thesis published (if at all) and how would you correct those errors?

Comment: It is still not published. Now I know where is these grammatical errors and I can fix them. I ask is there any rules in universities for cases like this?

Comment: Well, if the publication is independent of your degree, then you can do whatever you want with it. Otherwise, you have to check your institution’s rules and we cannot possibly answer this question.

Comment: you mean publications from my thesis. no.. I dont have yet. but interesting how the rules work if I want to fix grammatical corrections. how it works? if there any rules I can find? can you give me some link?

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase this: There are two possibilities: 1) You have to publish your thesis in some way as a requirement for obtaining your degree. In this case the institution granting the degree makes the rules and you have to ask them. 2) You want to publish your thesis for other reasons. In this case, there are no rules (at least regarding fixing minor errors). Why do you think there would be?

Comment: Strongly related questions: [Correcting a thesis after publication](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/94320/546) and [Found an error in my thesis](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/93530/546)

Comment: I should speak with my supervisor to find out what to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to amend it, then use some of the results from your thesis and get some papers published which the whole world sees. Ph.D. viva is an examination which has been graded. Forget about the thesis and move on with life not to make unnecessary mistakes anymore